Calibration plot in survival analysis
I'm trying to evaluate my parametric proportional hazards and accelerated failure models in terms of calibration. There seem to be many ways to summarise calibration, but they give a single summary metric which I don't think gives good insight into model's calibration.
I would much rather use a calibration plot. In my initial attempt, I used my models to predict the outcome at the time of censoring (time when the patient is assessed for presence of a condition- let's ignore interval-censoring for now), arranged patients into bins according to quantiles of the predicted risk, and then simply plotted the observed (N patients experiencing event in the bin/ N patients in the bin) against the mean risk of that quantile. The dot plot can then be augmented by a smoother, but I don't think that this is necessary. I also tried to "bootstrap" by resampling 100 times 1/3 of the population at a time, then plotting the smoother.
However, it seems (link) that this approach isn't what is recommended. I understand that I should have instead estimated the expected survival at a set time for all patients (say 1 year), then created quantile groups according to the expected survival, created a KM in each group and used its prediction at the same interval (1 year) as "observed" risk, and plotted a smoother.

is my original method completely inappropriate?
is my understanding of the "right" approach correct?


If possible, it would even be better to avoid binning and instead use methods that work in a continuous scale, outlined in the page you cite. Binning (if necessary for some reason) is less precise, as illustrated for parametric survival models in Section 19.4 of Regression Modeling Strategies (RMS), in Figure 19.11.
It's not clear (to me, at least) how the method that you propose will deal properly with censoring. The Kaplan-Meier estimates used in the binning method for calibration do handle censoring, provided that it isn't informative.
Another continuous assessment of a parametric survival model comes from a plot of the survival function of normalized, potentially censored model residuals. See this answer, Section 18.3.6 of RMS, Figure 18.10, and the example in RMS Figure 19.4. That's a more global visual estimate that combines information from all time points, perhaps more akin to what you had in mind but taking censoring into account.

Thanks @EdM. I can't use Harrell's calibrate as it doesn't work with my models, and I won't be able to implement it myself by hand. As for the AFT residuals- thank you for the interesting link, although I won't be able to apply it to my case (I need a method to apply to all my models, PH, AFT and a cloglog GLM). I think I will stick to bootstrapped, fine-grained binning method using a non-parametric estimate of S.
